# NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined "

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

CODE:

```
import networkx as net
from urllib.request import urlopen
def read_lj_friends(g, name):
# fetch the friend-list from LiveJournal
response=urllib.urlopen('http://www.livejournal.com/misc/fdata.bml?user='+name)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11):

You've imported `urlopen` directly, so you should refer to it like that rather than via `urllib`:

```
response = urlopen('...')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also try in Python 3:

```
from six.moves import urllib

temp_file, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just put `import urllib` at the top of your code

Answer (score 2):

Try pls:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
print(html.read) # Content
```

Comment: `urllib` is part of the standard library. You don't need to install `urllib3` which is a different library. Also, `urlopen` returns a file-like object, not the html.

Comment: Complicated, sorry. I'm fixing it. Thank you for warning.

Answer (score 0):

For your case:

```
import networkx as net
from urllib.request import urlopen
def read_lj_friends(g, name):
# fetch the friend-list from LiveJournal
response=urlopen('http://www.livejournal.com/misc/fdata.bml?user='+name)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post contains exactly the same code as in the original question, except for the stray back tick at the end. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.

Comment: Hey, thanks. The only change required in code is removing urllib in the last line of code. Please look once.