# ImportError: No module named parse - python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x

I have python 3.6.4 version.

I currently have this:

```
import scrapy
from JobScrapper import helper

try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse
```

and this is the (part) output and does not scrape anything:

```
NameError: global name 'urllib' is not defined
2018-01-16 12:42:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-01-16 12:42:49 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 261,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 41368,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 16, 4, 42, 49, 221000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NameError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 16, 4, 42, 45, 237000)}
2018-01-16 12:42:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Can you please help me sort this out? I am recently using python2, created virtualenv, replaced import urllib.parse to the code above.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314025/nameerror-name-urllib-is-not-defined) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314025/nameerror-name-urllib-is-not-defined)